# How to delete a node from a linked list using a function with node as a return type

Tags: java, function, object, linked-list, return-type

I' studying linked lists. I'm practicing problems from this book : *Cracking the coding interview*. I'm stuck, I can't understand how the author is trying to implement the following code, its supposed to delete a node....

```
class Node {

  Node next = null;
  int data;

  public Node (int d) {
    data = d;
  }

  Node deleteNode(Node head, int d) {
    Node n = head;

    if (n.data == d) {
      return head.next;
    }

    while (n.next != null) {
      if (n.next.data == d) {
         n.next = n.next.next;
         return head;
      }
      n = n.next;
    }
    return head;
  }
```

I've 3 questions...

**Question 1** - 
What are we going to pass as the argument for the function deleteNode? What purpose does Node head serve? and what purpose does int d serve? Is the node head the node we want to delete? Or is it our head node? I mean, we are supposed to use the method as following right?

```
"Name of node".deleteNode("Node name", "integer value");
```

"Name of node" being the node we want to delete...Isn't that right?

**Question 2** - Its clear in the code that the function deleteNode uses only data to confirm the identity of the node we want to delete. E.g. if(n.data ==d). Is that normal practice? I mean what if I have 2 different nodes containing the same integer as the data value? Shouldn't we use the name of the node to specify which node we want to delete?

**Question 3** - function deleteNode returns a node. Why is that? In order to delete a node, we only gotta do 3 things...First, unlink the pointer of the node we want to delete. Second, put the pointer of the previous node, to the node where the pointer of the node we wanted to delete was originally pointing. Third, delete the node now that its not linked to the list. I don't see what purpose does return type node serves here...

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1 :** All along your post, you keep talking about the "name" of the nodes, but the nodes have no name. They have an `int` value and a successor, that's all. In this `deleteNode` method, the first argument is the head of the linked list from which you want to remove the first occurrence of the value `d`.

**Question 2 :** As I said, the nodes have no name and are identified by their value. As soon as an occurrence of the wanted value is found, the corresponding node is deleted no matter how many occurrences of the same value are in the linked list.

**Question 3 :** the method returns the head of the list, so that you can chain multiple calls like this

```
myList.deleteNode(head,3).deleteNode(head,5).addNode(head,10)
```

If the method had a `void` return type, you should do

```
myList.deleteNode(head,3);
myList.deleteNode(head,5);
myList.addNode(head,10);
```

Comment: You are passing only the integer arguments when you call the deleteNode function. As you can see in the code, it requires 2 arguments...explanation?

Comment: Just forgotten it since it is unusual. The head would actually be expected to be `myList` in such a call.